# How to trigger button click event when the DataGridView cell has validation?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview

I have a tab control in which, the page1 has a DataGridView with cell validation. If I enter an invalid value in the cell and click on a the button which is out side of the grid, the error message is shown and if I edit the cell with valid value and then click again the button click event is raised. If I moved to tabpage2 with invalid value in the cell, the error message is shown. Whereas, the problem is, if I enter a valid value in the cell and then click on the button, the button click event was not raised.

Here is the code part for cell validation

```
private void DataGridView2_CellValidating(object sender,
DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)  
{
//To validate the cell
string text = e.FormattedValue.ToString();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter the value");
        e.Cancel = true;
     } 
}
```

I have attached a sample and video to replicate the issue.
Please have a look into this,

**Sample link:** https://1drv.ms/u/s!AieEPKCxZLyJ0ixXtuCKuiOf8dtL

**Video demo:** https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Me0VEvtrWZz8PkNnUPwVxuVzwLN6EBh2

**Replication procedure:**

1. Run the attached sample.
2. Delete the any cell value in Id column.
3. Click the tabpage2
4. Message box appears to enter the valid value.
5. press ok button. Then, enter the valid value in that cell.
6. Click on the button1

**Issue:**

Button1 click event has not raised.

can anyone let me know that the reason for the issue or to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Come up with the code that you are using, no one is going to see the shared video and follow the steps.

Comment: @un-lucky I have added my code part to validate the cell. Please have a look into this.

Comment: The vid is in a unsupported encoding format, the sample seems to work in my case, I remove a value, i click the button, it says please enter a valid value. I re-enter a value and click the button it says "button clicked". What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @iam.Carrot please remove the value and move to tab page. It will show the error message and enter the value in the cell and then click on the button. The "Button clicked" message box will not be shown.

Comment: Now I get it. Let me look into it